# Do in-app purchases show up in Google Checkout?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-checkout, sales-analytics

Regular Google Market purchases of one's apps show up in one's Google Checkout console. Click on Merchant Account and you'll see them.

Do in-app purchases show there as well?

If they do, how about dummy in-app purchases - the ones with dummy item ID (`android.test.purchased` and the like), and the ones made with designated test accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.test.purchased do not show up in the merchant account. But real item will show up. This is based on my experience.

Comment: What about real items fake-bought with a designated test Google account?

Comment: There is no fake-bought. You have to buy it for real, but you can refund full amount afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all in-app purchases will show up under your  [Orders tab](https://checkout.google.com/sell/orders).